# Blazor nullable Enum Select Component

Tags: blazor

I cannot find a way to create a component for a nullable enum select component.

I have no issue making one for a non nullable Enumeration like this:

```
@typeparam T where T : Enum

<MudSelect T="T" Clearable="Clearable" Value="Enumeration" ValueChanged="Callback" Label="@Label">
    @foreach (T item in Enum.GetValues(typeof(T))) {
        <MudSelectItem Value="item">
            @item.ToDescriptionString()
        </MudSelectItem>
    }
</MudSelect>

@code {

    [Parameter]
    public bool Clearable { get; set; }

    [Parameter, EditorRequired]
    public T Enumeration { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<T> EnumerationChanged { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string Label { get; set; } = typeof(T).ToString().Humanize();

    private Task Callback(T arg)
    {
        Enumeration = arg;
        return EnumerationChanged.InvokeAsync(arg);
    }

}
```

usage:

```
<EnumSelector T="CheckSeverity" @bind-Enumeration="CheckRequest.Severity"/>
```

I tried adding struct to T constraint.
I tried adding ? nullable operator on every T but I always get the error:

```
 The type 'CheckSeverity?' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'EnumSelector<T>'
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a separate parameter to handle the nullable value, and then assign the non-nullable value (if applicable) when you do get a value:

```
[Parameter] public T? NullableT { get; set; }

[Parameter]
public T TValue
{
    get { return _tvalue; }
    set
    {
        if (_tvalue != value)
        {
            _tvalue = value;

            NullableT = value;

            if (TValueChanged.HasDelegate)
                TValueChanged.InvokeAsync(value);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm having trouble implementing your solution. Do you have an example of this solution?

Comment: @R.Haughton This is the example that I figured out to suit my issue. In my case I used a nullable integer as the value, but had no trouble in my control.